# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception in hackerrank Cut the sticks

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to implement a problem in Hackerrank Cut the sticks. Problem can be found [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cut-the-sticks/problem) 
my code is this

```
static int[] cutTheSticks(int[] arr) 
{
    int n = arr.Length, k = 0;
    int[] result = new int[n];
    Array.Sort(arr);
    Array.Reverse(arr);

    while(arr.Length != 0)
    {
        result[k] = arr.Length;
        k++;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            arr[i] -= arr[arr.Length - 1];
        } 
    }

    return result;
}
```

it shows error as-

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>   at Solution.cutTheSticks (System.Int32[] arr) [0x00020] in solution.cs:24

line 24 is:

```
result[k] = arr.Length;
```

How to remove this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Comment: Considering that you don't remove any elements from `arr`, when will `arr.Length!=0` ever become false? Think about what happens inside your infinite loop, for example with `k` and `result[k]`...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah I understand that loop is running for infinite times. How to remove the element ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code. To name a few:

You are giving the result array a fixed size (`int[] result=new int[n];`), but it's size depends entirely on how many duplicate values are contained in the list.

You are supposed to remove from the array the smallest value(s) in each iteration. However you are just modifying the values (`arr[i] -= arr[arr.Length - 1];`), not removing them, so the array length will remain the same, and thus `while (arr.Length != 0)` will always be true, creating an endless loop. This causes `k++` to keep incrementing until it reaches a value greater than the array length, which then results in the exception you are getting.

Since you are supposed to change the size of the input array, I suggest using `List<int>` instead, here's an example:

```
List<int> output = new List<int>();
List<int> input = new List<int>(arr);

while (input.Count > 0)
{
    output.Add(input.Count);
    int min = input.Min();
    input.RemoveAll(x => x == min);
    input.ForEach(x => x -= min);
}

return output.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to add condition `k < n` before assigning value to avoid `IndexOutOfRangeException` exception. In addition, there is a strong need a condition to avoid infinite `while` loop :

```
static int[] cutTheSticks(int[] arr) {
    int n = arr.Length,
            k = 0;
    int[] result = new int[n];
    Array.Sort(arr);
    Array.Reverse(arr);
    while (arr.Length != 0)
    {
            if (k < n)
                result[k] = arr.Length;
            else
                break;
            k++;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                arr[i] -= arr[arr.Length - 1];
            }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

It is possible to pop out one element after every iteration like this:

```
static int[] cutTheSticks(int[] arr)
{
    int n = arr.Length,
            k = 0;
    int[] result = new int[n];
    var arrToBeRemoved = arr.ToList();
    Array.Sort(arr);
    Array.Reverse(arr);
    while (arr.Length != 0)
    {
        if (k < n)
            result[k] = arr.Length;
        else
            break;

        if (k < arrToBeRemoved.Count)
            arrToBeRemoved.RemoveAt(k);

        arr = arrToBeRemoved.ToArray();
        k++;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
        {
            arr[i] -= arr[arr.Length - 1];
        }
     }
     return result;
}
```

Comment: that worked but in the last i want to pop out one element after every iteration, Can u suggest a solution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it that way:

```
static int[] cutTheSticks(int[] arr)
{
    List<int> results = new List<int>();
    int cutted = 0;
    while (cutted != 1)
    {
        cutted = 0;
        int min = GetMin(arr);
        if (min == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] >= min)
            {
                arr[i] -= min;
                cutted++;
            }
        }
        results.Add(cutted);
    }
    return results.ToArray();
}

static int GetMin(int[] arr)
{
    int min = int.MaxValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] != 0 && arr[i] < min)
        {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```